# Cannot recall image saved in directory to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, directory, save, uicollectionview

I cannot recall the image saved in the directory and show on the UICollectionView.  Is there a possibility that I have left out something?  I have added logs so that I can see what is happening and both i and j do come out but crashes saying

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<HatsCell 0x208940c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3467c2a3 0x3c36097f 0x3467bf99 0x34ee91d9 0x366282b9 0x34ee4f2b 0x3460261b 0x3662131d 0x3689f077 0x3689f56b 0xa0911 0x3689a02d 0x3689af25 0x3689c7bb 0x36487803 0x36231d8b 0x36231929 0x3623285d 0x36232243 0x36232051 0x36231eb1 0x346516cd 0x3464f9c1 0x3464fd17 0x345c2ebd 0x345c2d49 0x3818a2eb 0x364d8301 0x8e7cd 0x3c797b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is my recall code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"hats";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionHats.delegate =self;
    collectionHats.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSLog(@"i");
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
        }}}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"j");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [allImagesArray count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseID = @"ReuseID";
    HatsCell *mycell = (HatsCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return mycell;
}
```

This is for my .h in hats cell

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HatsCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageInCell;

@end
```

Comment: Show the definition of `HatsCell`. The exception has nothing to do with image loading directly.

Comment: That isn't the definition...

Comment: The .h file contains the definition, the .m file is the implementation.

Comment: I updated my question.  I call .h file declaration file.. so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you're trying to set the `image` of your `HatsCell` instance. `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't have this property and `HatsCell` doesn't add it so you get an exception. You should instead be setting the image of the cells `imageInCell`.

---

When you get the cell:

```
HatsCell *mycell = (HatsCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You then need to update it:

```
mycell.imageInCell.image = [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: You don't show code which causes the exception. It may be in your XIB where you're trying to set the image view to a property which doesn't exist...

Comment: So it's probably in the XIB, not the code. Check all of the outlet connections in the XIB and see if there is one called `image`. If there is, remove it.